# CSS/JSX: Fixing two HTML canvas within a div with relative width as 60% and 40%

Tags: css, reactjs, rxjs, chart.js

I have two charts as shown below:
[image]

Note that this is a canvas representation. I want to pack another similar chart and this one in a row layout with first one occupying 60% of the total width and the next one occupying as 40% of the total width.

I want to pack them within the div but the way they appear is like this:
[image]

I don't want these two canvas to occupy 100% of the width instead share the screen with in 60:40. My container class is as follows:

```
.SummaryWrapper {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #ccc, -1px 1px #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* animation: mymove 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3; */
}
```

whereas when I use display as `display:inline`:
[image]

Can someone suggest a better workaround to force fix it within the given div? This is a react component btw... the chart... here's the [reproduction link](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-brook-tv3tw?file=/src/Components/Summary.module.css).

Comment: your reproduction link do not contain the canvas. but the solution would be `display: inline-flex` with some `width:60%` and `flex:1`

Comment: this is supposed to be applied to canvas property? For example: `.CanvasClass1 {display: inline-flex; width: 60%; flex: 1;} .CanvasClass2 {display: inline-flex; width: 40%; flex: 1;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solution you can apply to achieve what you want.

Here is one example =>

basically, your wrapper use

```
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
```

your canvas fill the space available, and are contained by 2 div that do the sizing

```
width: "60%"
position: "relative"
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-river-dh3xu